# how to pass the data in between activity to fragment using bundle in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I can store the value in one variable. Now I want pass that variable into a fragment 
Using the code below, I am able to load fragments:

```
public class AndroidListFragmentActivity extends Activity {
    Fragment2 f2;
    public static String itemname;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.apetiserfragement);
        itemname=getIntent().getStringExtra("itemname");
        Bundle args=new Bundle();
        args.putString("itemname", itemname);
        f2=new Fragment2();
        f2.setArguments(args);
    }
} /* (Here I load fragment using xml page) itemname */
```

The output is splitted into 2 windows one for extend for listfragment (for listview) and one for fragments.

Fragment2.xml

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    String itemname;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(getArguments().getString("itemname"));

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

AndroidListFragmentActivity in this class itemname I want pass Fragment2.class.. please help me

Comment: See this response here : [data sharing beetween fragments and activity in androidi][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445594/data-sharing-between-fragments-and-activity-in-android/20521851#20521851

Answer (score 3):

If both fragment are on other activity then can use intent

if on same activity then can do operation on that particular activity

as in this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)

see onListItemClick of class TitlesFragment

```
**
     * Helper function to show the details of a selected item, either by
     * displaying a fragment in-place in the current UI, or starting a
     * whole new activity in which it is displayed.
     */
    void showDetails(int index) {
        mCurCheckPosition = index;

        if (mDualPane) {//<---------------------f on same activity then can do operation on that particular fragment
            // We can display everything in-place with fragments, so update
            // the list to highlight the selected item and show the data.
            getListView().setItemChecked(index, true);

            // Check what fragment is currently shown, replace if needed.
            DetailsFragment details = (DetailsFragment) //<------------------------see use getFragmentManager
                    getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details);
            if (details == null || details.getShownIndex() != index) {
                // Make new fragment to show this selection.
                details = DetailsFragment.newInstance(index);

                // Execute a transaction, replacing any existing fragment
                // with this one inside the frame.
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.details, details);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.commit();
            }

        } else { //<----------If both fragment are on other activity then can use intent 
            // Otherwise we need to launch a new activity to display
            // the dialog fragment with selected text.
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("index", index);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: i use intent . but it application force quit..please help

Comment: the above answer not suitable solution for me

Answer (score 0):

See this response here : [data sharing between fragments and activity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445594/data-sharing-between-fragments-and-activity-in-android/20521851#20521851)