# Data Sharing between Fragments and Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, data-sharing

Ive asked a similar question before and didn't get an answer and seems many other ppl are searching for an answer. So I am posting this question to hopefully get a clear answer that everyone can benefit from.

I have an activity with 2 fragments in it. I want fragment2 to set a boolean variable in Activity when a checkbox is checked so that fragment1 can know if the checkbox was checked.

This is my Code:

Activity:

```
public class modestab extends Activity{
    public static Context appContext;

    public boolean lf=false;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        appContext=this;
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
ActionBar tabbar= getActionBar();
        tabbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ActionBar.Tab ModesTab =tabbar.newTab().setText("Modes");
        ActionBar.Tab CatTab =tabbar.newTab().setText("Categories");

        Fragment ModesFragment =new modes();
        Fragment CatFragment =new cats();

        ModesTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(ModesFragment));
        CattTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(CatFragment));

        tabbar.addTab(ModesTab);
        tabbar.addTab(CatTab);


    }
```

Fragment 1:(Where I want to read the boolean lf set in Acitivity above:

```
@TargetApi(11)
public class tabmodes extends Fragment{
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
View V=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_modes, container, false);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(lf==false) //lf here is the lf in Activity which I want to get
```

Fragment 2: Where I want to set lf in Activity

```
.....
lifecheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
              @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                  if(lifecheck.isChecked())
                      getActivity().lf=true;//Where I want to set the lf flag in Activity
                  ;
              }
          });
```

The code doesn't compile and I am not knowing how to set lf in the Activity nor how to read it. Someone suggested I do getActivity() but I am not able to see the variable.

I tried to create a function setlf(boolean jk) but also I am not able to see it...

Any help is welcome :)

Answer (score 121):

Many ways :

1) **Activity -> Fragment**

- *In your Activity* : create a bundle and use **fragment.[setArguments(bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments%28android.os.Bundle%29)**
- *in your Fragment*  : use **Bundle bundle = [getArguments()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getArguments%28%29)**

2) **Activity -> Fragment**

- *In your Fragment* : create a public method
- *In your Activity* : call an **active** fragment public method :

  [getSupportFragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager%28%29)().[findFragmentById](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentById%28int%29)(R.id.your_fragment).publicMethod(args)

3) **Fragment -> Activity**

- *In your Fragment* : create un interface with getter and setter methods ([callback methods](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity))
- *In your Activity* : implement the interface

4) **Fragment -> Activity**

- *In your Activity* : Create public getter and setter or other methods
- *In your Fragment* : called public activity getter, setter or other methods using :

  [getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29).getSomething(), [getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29).setSomething(args) or [getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29).someMethod(args)

Comment: You just solved a big problem for me and saved me a whole bunch of work. Thanks!

Comment: why is it bad to use a static variable . and cant we use a static object instead of static methods and variables

Comment: Nicely written answer with multiple options really helps.  I'm wondering about the trade-offs of each (are there benefits or negatives to each? - or are they all basically equal?) and are these still the 4 main ways in the present (2019) since this answer is 6 years old?  Just curious.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass data between fragments in two ways,

First, you can do it by using [setArguments(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments%28android.os.Bundle%29) and [getArguments(....)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getArguments%28%29)

Second,you can do it using [Call back](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks)

Comment: Is this the only way to share data by passing arguments between the fragments?
can't I set and get the variables in the activity directly?

Comment: Otherwise you can use sharedpreferences for data sharing

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, do you have any example on the setArguments and getArguments

Comment: For a question that specifically asks for clear answers, yours doesn't help much.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use **EventBus**. It's really simple. 
https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Definitely don't use static methods like my old answer :)