# Pass ArrayList of object to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, serialization, arraylist, parcelable

I have `ArrayList<DataChannels> dataChannelsArrayList = new ArrayList<>()`

and `DataChannels.java`:

```
public class DataChannels {
    private DataRequestStatus dataRequestStatus;
    private ArrayList<Channel> channelArrayList;

...getters-setters...
}
```

and `Channel.java`:

```
class Channel{
   private String id;
   private String taxonomy_name;
   private String ch_id;
   private String lang;
   private String name;
   private String __v;
   private String sort;
   private boolean active;

...getters-setters...
}
```

`DataRequestStatus.java`:

```
public class DataRequestStatus {
private String status;
private String error;

...getters-setters...
```

}

And I can't really understand how to pass that `ArrayList<DataChannels> dataChannelsArrayList` to `Fragment` from `Activity`.

I have tried `Serializeble` interface. Did not work. And wanna try `Parcelable` but don't know how to implement `writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags)` properly.

Please help me. Its really confusing.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20521851/745750

Comment: thanks, but that approach involves tight coupling between classes. I would be better to serialize it somehow and pass by intent. But I don't know how since the hierarchy is too complicated...