# Send data between fragments using Shared Preferences

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, fragment, sharedpreferences

What the code should do: in the first fragment I have several EditText boxes, so people can fill in there name. In the second fragment I want the names to display in a TextView box. I thought using Shared Preferences was a good thing (correct me if I'm wrong).

In my first fragment I have this code:

```
public static String filename = "player1";
SharedPreferences someData;
[...]
someData = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
String player1 = etPlayer1.getText().toString();
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = someData.edit();
editor.putString(player1, "player1");
editor.commit();
```

In my second fragment:

```
public static String filename = "player1";
SharedPreferences someData;
[...]
points1 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvPoints1);
someData = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
String dataReturned = someData.getString("player1", "Player 1");
points1.setText(dataReturned);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use an Intent or a Bundle. Shared Preferences are for storing long term data.

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10960855/826657

and this one for how to share data using a Bundle https://stackoverflow.com/a/16500141/826657

& this resource

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: How do I send data using a bundle. I tried to send data but my application crashes. I have to send a string from the first fragment to the second.

Answer (score 1):

Please pass your data (specially if complex) in a Bundle as explained here: [Best practice for instantiating a new Android Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment)

Do not use shared preferences to do that.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to pass data between activity and fragment. See this response here : [data sharing between fragments and activity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445594/data-sharing-between-fragments-and-activity-in-android/20521851#20521851)